# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, apk

I'm trying to build an android app using Github Actions(react native) but getting an error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Bayanihan'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:.
        Required by:
            project :
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
  
BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Version details:
java 8 , gradle is also 8, android is 34 and node is 16.

Comment: Here is github action workflow:
```          
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
          cd android
          ./gradlew --status
          ./gradlew --stop
          cd ~
          sudo rm -rf .gradle

      - name: Update Gradle Wrapper
        run: |
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android
          ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.0.1
          ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had the somewhat same issue. In my case, I was missing

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
```

The line from settings.gradle file.

After adding it problem solved